# LoadCompleted Not Firing in WPF WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a simple WPF webBrowser control that I am using to automate a website.  The page that I'm trying to load is an ASP.NET page.  When I try to navigate to it normally, LoadCompleted is never fired.  If I try to navigate to it, and read the elements with an IHTMLElementCollection in the Navigated event, then the LoadCompleted event does fire.  It doesn't make sense to me.  The LoadCompleted event should fire regardless, because I'm loading a page in both situations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out for those events to work correctly the control has to be visible.  I had been trying to show the control at the end after everything processed, but that will not work.