# How to know if wpf webbrowser has completed loading the page(not using Loadcomplete)

Tags: vb.net, wpf-controls

I am currently trying to use a web browser created dynamically in code to extract details in a web page, but I am unable to know when the load is complete. I know there is a `.LoadCompleted` event.
I tried it and it is not firing for some reason, so I dropped it. 
But I am kind of looking for the type where we used to do for winforms webbrowser control. I'm checking if the document is ready like this:

```
Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
  Application.DoEvents()
Loop
```

Is there anything similar? So that I can check and continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: as mentioned I am creating the webbrowser on the fly and it is not visible. I am creating and destroying it because I have to loop through lot of web pages and frequently used to get "out of memory" message

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web browser control is visible. Some events may not fire if the web browser control is hidden.

Related: [LoadCompleted Not Firing in WPF WebBrowser Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585565/loadcompleted-not-firing-in-wpf-webbrowser-control)

**References**

- [Web Browser Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc490830.aspx)
- [LoadCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted.aspx)

Comment: i dont want it to be visible. is there any other method. i can use forms webbrowser. but i will have to use doevents to get that running and loading. and i really want to avoid that as much as possible

Comment: Just make it visible, pull the data, then make it invisible again. That's the only way it is going to work unfortunately.